# JavaScript rounding to 1 decimal place on inline style attribute

Tags: javascript

I have function which is generating random RGBA color and if I log it to the console it is rounding to on decimal place(that is what I want), but if you open console and try this as inline style attribute on body element you can see that it's not rounding to one decimal place ? Where is the problem ?

[**JSFIDDLE(backgroundColor)**](http://jsfiddle.net/htmlBOYY/9cttz9zr/)

```
setInterval(function foo (){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = ("rgba(" + Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + "," + Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + "," + Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + "," + Math.random().toFixed(1)) + ")";
},1000);
```

[**JSFIDDLE(console.log)**](http://jsfiddle.net/htmlBOYY/54rownt5/)

**JS**

```
setInterval(function foo (){
  console.log(("rgba(" + Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + "," + Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + "," + Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + "," + Math.random().toFixed(1)) + ")");
},1000);
```

If you compare these two fiddles you can see the difference.So why are they different? It is same function and it should be same, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser internally stores the alpha value as 1 byte, not as a float. When for example you say you need a 0.5 alpha, the browser converts that into 1 byte integer using this:

```
Math.floor(255 * 0.5)
```

When you query the result back, it wil convert that integer back to 0-1 range by dividing with 255.

This will result in an incorrect alpha. I've tested this using this:

```
rgba(134,78,73,0.5) //the color outputed by javascript
rgba(134, 78, 73, 0.498039) //the color that was read back from the style
```

`0.498039 = Math.floor(255 * 0.5) / 255;` (of course with some rounding)

Comment: What way I can convert this to one decimal in browser ? Is it possible ?

Comment: It is sadly not possible as the resolution of the alpha channel doesn't allow it. However please keep in mind that you shouldn't read back values from the DOM, as there is no guarantee you'll receive the same as it was set to. For example by setting "rgb(255, 255, 255)" the browser might report rgba back, or "#FFFFFF" or even "white". You should store the set values somewhere in you application.